# Hex string to int string and vice versa

Tags: c#

I would like to convert some huge hex string to int string.

my hex string can be somthing like that: 
666E7A427931676468633533394553764B38483240384A4B615241333455455A3369386F366048745A333932367A6A664142462F57574273

this number is too long to be store in an int, and I need to get it in a string as integer

and how to convert my new int string back in hex ?

have you some idea to do that?

Comment: Any int?  Are you looking for a hash or what?

Comment: What about [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: do you meant you want that value as a base 10 number?

Comment: I'm just looking for the integer representation of my hex string

Comment: hell yeah BigInteger I forgot it we can parse some Hex string with it

Comment: To say "integer representation" is meaningless.  Technically, it's already an integer, as it has no decimal (um... radix) point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) (.NET 4.0+) to obtain the base 10 representation.

```
var hexString = "666E7A427931676468633533394553764B38483240384A4B615241333455455A3369386F366048745A333932367A6A664142462F57574273"
var bigNumber = BigInteger.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
```

The result is

```
290825075527865440850840162776336047300722068695844686969687688283360481878315042200208855384521898951434440464937388090234036230242931
```

You can store it as a `string` from there if it's more convenient for you.

Comment: i think he is right more reference about this `BigInteger` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx